# How to get length of a specific column in a table

Tags: c#, database

I am trying to get the length of a specific column in a table which table is from a database called `Users` in a visual studio C# form application. First of all i know it has to do with the `column.length` command but since those examples i have a searched i got lost.

Can someone tell me a simple way to get this happen? For more specific information i have a table called `user_info` and it contains a column which name is `searches`. I want to get the length of searches into a single variable

Comment: You mean something like `SELECT COUNT(searches) FROM user_info`?

Comment: Are you asking for help with the SQL portion? Or the C# portion? Please be more specific as to what exactly you have/haven't tried, post your source code, and point out where you're having a problem

Comment: Yes i want first to `SELECT` the column and then get the length of the selected column

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71340230/8644294

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the C# code that you need to pull the column size from the database.  Make sure you update the connString variable to contain your own SQL server connection string.

Example: `"Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Northwind;server=(local)"`

```
Int32 columnSize = 0;
string sql = "SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'user_info' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'searches'";
string connString = "Your Sql Server Connection String";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
   try
   {
      conn.Open();
      columnSize = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Comment: `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` can you tell me the specific meaning of this ?

Comment: CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH is the Maximum length, in characters, for binary data, character data, or text and image data.

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view allows you to get information about all columns for all tables and views within a database.


https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/183/informationschemacolumns/