# How to count characters length from a column in database and put them in a new column showing in datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

Basically, I have a database with a table named anuncios with this columns:

```
idAnnouncements | title | message | idClients (foreign key)|
```

, and I have another table named detalhefatura with this columns:

```
idAnnouncements | idFatura (foreign  key) | subTotal
```

IN C#: When I click in a button, I want to count the letters from the message column in Announcements table, and put them into the column subTotal, like this

http://prntscr.com/mbijxs

Is it needed a query or only c# code?

This is what I got, to put in the label u see in the printscreen above, the amount of all characters with the same ClientID

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        {
            var linhas = dataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(r => Convert.ToString(r.Cells["mensagem"].Value));
            double somaLinhas = linhas.Sum(r => r.Length * 0.02);
            lbltotal.Text = string.Format(@"{0:#,##0.00}", somaLinhas);


        }

    }
```

Comment: if you want the lenght ot something, I sugeest using SQL and not c# to do so. Also please show your work until now, this helps gauge what you need exactly.

Comment: @WiseStrawberry I'll edit the post then

Comment: I guess you have the answer here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40405687/how-to-get-length-of-a-specific-column-in-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

```
      columnSize = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

after this:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value = columnSize;
```

Comment: Did you look a bit to this link and see if your answer is here?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40405687/how-to-get-length-of-a-specific-column-in-a-table

Comment: i looked at it, not what I want